Construct a unitary matrix from $2^k$ vectors
Suppose $u_{1},\,\cdots,\,u_{2^{k}} \in M_{N_{\sigma},K}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy:
\begin{align*}
   &\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}=I_{N_{\sigma}}; \\
   &u_{i}u_{j}^{T}=u_{j}u_{i}^{T},\,1\leq i,\,j \leq 2^{k}.
\end{align*}
that is,
\begin{equation*}
  \left[\begin{array}{c}
     u_{1} \\
     u_{2} \\
     \vdots \\
     u_{2^{k}} \\
   \end{array}\right]
   \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
     u_{1}^{T} & u_{2}^{T} & \cdots &  u_{2^{k}}^{T} \\
   \end{array}\right]
   =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
     u_{1}u_{1}^{T} & u_{1}u_{2}^{T} & \cdots & u_{1}u_{2^{k}}^{T} \\
     u_{2}u_{1}^{T} & u_{2}u_{2}^{T} & \cdots & u_{2}u_{2^{k}}^{T}  \\
     \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
     u_{2^{k}}u_{1}^{T} & u_{2^{k}}u_{2}^{T} & \cdots & u_{2^{k}}u_{2^{k}}^{T} \\
   \end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
is a block matrix in which all blocks are symmetric and the sum of diagonal blocks is a identity matrix.
Let
\begin{equation*}
  \left(
     \begin{array}{ccccccc}
       S_{1} & S_{2} & S_{3} & S_{4} & \cdots & S_{2^{k}-1} & S_{2^{k}} \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
  =\left(
     \begin{array}{ccccccc}
       u_{1} & u_{2} & u_{3} & u_{4} & \cdots & u_{2^{k}-1} & u_{2^{k}} \\
       u_{2} & u_{1} & u_{4} & u_{3} & \cdots & u_{2^{k}}   & u_{2^{k}-1} \\
       u_{3} & u_{4} & u_{1} & u_{2} & \cdots & u_{2^{k}-3} & u_{2^{k}-2} \\
       u_{4} & u_{3} & u_{2} & u_{1} & \cdots & u_{2^{k}-2} & u_{2^{k}-3} \\
       \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
       u_{2^{k}-1} & u_{2^{k}} & u_{2^{k}-3} & u_{2^{k}-2} & \cdots & u_{1} & u_{2} \\
       u_{2^{k}} & u_{2^{k}-1} & u_{2^{k}-2} & u_{2^{k}-3} & \cdots & u_{2} & u_{1} \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
\end{equation*}
$\mathbf{Question:}$
Given $S_{1}$,
how to add a negative sign to $u_{1},\,\cdots,\,u_{2^{k}}$ of $S_{2}-S_{2^{k}}$, and denote these matrices are $\tilde{S}_{2}-\tilde{S}_{2^{k}}$, such that
\begin{equation*}
  S_{1}S_{1}^{T}+\tilde{S}_{2}\tilde{S}_{2}^{T}+\cdots+\tilde{S}_{2^{k}}\tilde{S}_{2^{k}}^{T}=I_{2^{k}N_{\sigma}}.
\end{equation*}
